# How can i respond to model changes from within my custom directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a collection, with models and each one of these models is managing the progress callback of a promise; updating every second with a new time stamp.

Model looks like:

```
 Model = {
            promise: promiseObject,
            name: videoName,
            uploadProgress: timestamp
        }
```

myAppUploadingCardCtrl has reference to the Collection here:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers')
    .controller('myAppUploadingCardCtrl', function ($scope, uploadingVideoCollection) {

    $scope.uploadingVideos = uploadingVideoCollection.collection;

});
```

Models are append to the DOM here:

```
<div ng-controller="myAppUploadingCardCtrl">
        <my-app-uploading-card ng-repeat="video in uploadingVideos" video-name="    {{video.name}}"
                           uploading-progress="{{video.uploadProgress}}">
    </my-app-uploading-card>
</div>
```

myAppUploadingCard Directive:

```
angular.module('myApp.directives')
    .directive('myAppUploadingCard', function (progressBarFactory) {

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {  

       var progressBar = element.find(.progressBar);
       function updateProgressBar(newTime) {
         progressBar.update(newTime)
       }
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            videoName: '@',
            uploadingProgress: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: 'views/templates/studio/videoList/uploadingCardTemplate.html',
        link: link,
        controller: function ($scope) {

        }
    }

});
```

I need to update an element (progress bar) inside the directive with the new model.uploadProgress value each time it changes. For example, triggering the updateProgressBar function defined in the linker function. Basically do something with a changed value.

I have attempted to do this with a $watch in the directive controller:

```
$scope.$watch($scope.uploadingProgress, function(e){
                console.log(e);
            })
```

And observe in the linker function:

```
     attrs.$observe('uploadingProgress', function(e){
            console.log(e);
        })
```

Nothing has worked for me thus far, and i need a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: The first parameter in the $watch function is a string. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385196/watch-function-in-directive-not-getting-triggered-in-angular-js/13385215

Comment: This does not work for me:                                        function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch("uploadingProgress", function (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }, true);
        } Fires once. I have an interval changing the value in the model every second, don't see the changes.

Comment: If you are using `setInterval` you will need to trigger a digest cycle via the `$apply` method on the scope. However, I would recommend using the built in `$interval` service. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Comment: That `$watch` only fires once because the `$observe` function doesn't set the new value on `$scope` it only logs it to the console.  Because your directive uses `uploadProgress : '@'` the value of `$scope.uploadProgress` will be set exactly once, if you used bi-directional binding as I've described below you wouldn't need the `$observe`

Comment: The brackets in your directive's attributes are not needed, `uploading-progress="{{video.uploadProgress}}"` should just be `uploading-progress="video.uploadProgress"` same with the name attribute

Comment: I get the value "video.uploadProgress" through with the Top Down (@) binding but the correct value with the two way binding (=) ... Doesn't resolve my issue though. :(

Comment: I changed the setInterval in the model to use $interval (btw its there just to mock the value change) - Still i get no changes .. i can see the value changing in the model but not in the directive. Im concerned there is something fundamentally wrong, and i'm overlooking it. Link function currently:        scope.$watch("uploadingProgress", function(e){
                console.log(e);
            })

Comment: sorry the `{{}}` is needed for variables with `@` - my bad on that one

Comment: ;) Is passing the value through via the attributes even the best/correct way to do this?

Comment: passing via attributes is fine.  here's a simple example that may give you an idea: http://jsfiddle.net/mikeeconroy/cMYYk/2/

Comment: here's another that shows an example using a `$watch` statement: http://jsfiddle.net/mikeeconroy/cMYYk/3/

Comment: Solved! Looks like i wasn't too far off, i think the afternoon of hacking at it had left my codebase in disarray. Your fiddles were key for me get this sorted though. I've put the binding back to Top Down (@), and also without @dnc253 recommendation to use $interval instead of window.setInterval, thus triggering $digest, id still be stuck! Thanks!

Comment: @Twig2let, no problem glad we could send in you in the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your directive's scope property for `uploadingProgress` to be two-way bound.

```
...
scope: {
    videoName: '@',
    uploadingProgress: '='
}...
```

Doing this you won't have to set up an `$observe` on the attribute or a `$watch` on the scope, once the value changes in the parent controller the directive will receive the new value as well.

EDIT: I guess it depends on how you have the directive's template setup, if you directly use `$scope.uploadingProgess` in the template you won't need a `$watch` for example:

```
<div class="progressBar" width="{{uploadProgress|someFilterPerhaps}}"></div>
```

or if you don't use it directly then you'll need that `$watch` function:

```
$scope.$watch('uploadingProgress',function(newVal,oldVal){
    ... do something with the new value here ...
});
```

**EDIT:** Here's a simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mikeeconroy/cMYYk/2/ and this one with a `$watch` function: http://jsfiddle.net/mikeeconroy/cMYYk/3/

Comment: this throws the error: syntax Error: Token 'video.name' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression [{{video.name}}] starting at [video.name}}].  I'm wanting to pass the new value to an injected service on the directive. Not use it directly.

Comment: If you don't use it directly you'll then need the `$watch` statement as I cited above.

Comment: not sure why setting up the bi-directional binding on the one scope variable would affect the other scope variable